# adding software components to eclipse

Tags: eclipse, configuration, installation, eclipse-3.6

I have an eclipse installation from the "[Eclipse for PHP Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-php-developers/heliosr)" package and I want to "extend" it to have in addition to the PHP components all the components of "[Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/heliosr)".
but the Feature Lists in the above links do not match the items I am presented when I choose "Install new software..."  from the eclipse help menu.

Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: OK, I just found out that there is a features folder under the root folder of eclipse. will it work if I just copy the feature files from the Java EE download into the features folder of the PHP Developers one ?

Comment: yes it should do. That's the whole idea of plugable components in eclipse. Don't forget to install the WTP components too under the http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/helios update site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the result of copying plugins/features into that folder is not that predictable and hence not safe. Eclipse adviced to install plugins via "Install new Software" - it will tell you about conflicts (like different plugins use different version of another plugin" etc; or you need to install another plugin etc.) Otherwise I had situations when it didn't work and I got no idea why (had to read logs to figure it out).

Well, to install new plugin you have few possibilities:
1) "Install new Software" - you already tried it. Take into account that the list of plugins by default is limited here. But below the button "Add..." you can see "Available Software Sites" - this list is enhanced, and some of plugins you can find here". **UPDATE:** the process of installation is described [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/PDT/Installation#Eclipse_3.6_.2F_Helios_.2F_PDT_2.2)

2) With new Eclipse (Helios) you got new way to add plugins, so called [Eclipse Marketplace](http://www.eclipse.org/mpc/) (Help/Eclipse Marketplace...). This is recommended way to look and install new plugins.

Back to your problem - I think it is much more easier to download Java IDE for Java EE Developers, and install PHP  Development Tools there. In Marketplace I selected Yoxos as source, typed "pdt" and found plugins related to PDTs (although I'm not sure there are all parts of it)

Comment: Yes, I got this suggestion from a friend as well. I guess I will have to try it our.
will be back to accept as answer or comment further after I check this out.
Is PDT the only thing I will need to add ?

Comment: should be so (only PDT). Unbelievable, but [eclipse wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/PDT/Installation#Eclipse_3.6_.2F_Helios_.2F_PDT_2.2) tells how to add it only using Install New Software menu item, nothing about MarketPlace...